# Compactness of a finite set, and non-compactness of $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Determine which of the following sets are compact. Prove they are compact or not.
1) Let $S = \{1, 2, \ldots , N\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ equipped with the discrete metric for $N < \infty$.

2) $S = \mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$

I know that for each of these, I need to prove that every open contains a finite sub cover. But am confused as to how to show that. Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The "$N<\infty$" comment isn't needed, since $\{1,2,\dots,\infty\}$ isn't a subset of $\Bbb Z$ (as $\infty\notin\Bbb Z$).

Answer (score 1):

For (1) this is almost trivial because the set contains only a *finite* number of points!  Given any any cover for the set, at most n of the sets contains the n points in the set.

For (2), for any integer n, the open interval (n-1/4, n+ 1/4) contain n and no other integer.  Do you see that dropping even **one** of those sets will no longer cover Z?

Comment: Yea dropping one of those sets, would no longer cover one value in Z, but how does this make it that the open cover does not have a finite subcover?

Comment: Think about it..

Comment: is it because the a finite subcover minus a term no longer covers the whole set?? I really have no idea

Comment: @JacobRodgers The open cover $\{(n-\frac14,n+\frac14):n\in\Bbb Z\}$ covers $\Bbb Z$. It is an infinite cover, as there is an open interval for every integer. Does it have a finite subcover?

Comment: Does it have _any_ subcover? (Other than itself)

Comment: So if you wanted to take a subcover of this open cover, you couldn't because then the new subcover no longer contains all the elements??

Answer (score 0):

As for (1), let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $S$. For each number $k\in S$, pick an index $i_k$, such that $k\in U_{i_k}$. Then $S\subseteq U_{i_1}\cup\cdots \cup U_{i_N}$, which is a finite subcover.

As for (2), the set $\mathbb{Z}$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$. To see this, try choosing the specific open cover ${(-n,n)}_{\{n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ and think about why this does not have a finite subcover. To be clear, each element in this cover is an open interval of the form $(-n,n)$, e.g. $(-1,1)$, $(-7,7)$ etc.

Comment: Does (2) not have a finite subcover since the open interval you choose (-n,n) could have n=infinity, which is not finite?

Comment: @JacobRodgers no, the cover I chose only has intervals of the form $(-n,n)$, where $n$ is finite. But it still covers $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, if $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is some integer, then $k$ is contained in the open interval $(-(k+1),k+1)$.